# BOOTSTRAP NAV Collapsed Colapse alterando height alinhamento

Tags: bootstrap, nav-bar, css

Problema:  preciso de um navbar com HEIGHT MAIOR.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alterei o css

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-collapse .collapse .in {
    padding-top:80px;
}
```

1. O alinhamento vertical dos links nao fica verticalmente centralizado
2. Quando collapsed, o menu esta invadindo o espaço do logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu HTML coloque o teu navbar dentro de uma classe chamada .header por exemplo. Dentro desta classe trabalhe o tamanho dela nas suas determinadas media queries. O seu logo vc tb pode colocar ele com a classe img-responsive e trabalhar o tamanho dele em cada media queries tb.

ex: 
normal(desktop)
.header { 
height: 200px
}
Media celular:
.header {height: 100px}